# Getting sum on multiply and get the average after

Tags: mysql, sql, average

i have table that looks like this

```
n1 | n2 | n3 |   n4   
---------------------
40   60   40     30   
50   50   55.5   20  
80   40   40.5   30
```

i want to multiply each column to

```
n1*0.7
n2*0.1
n3*0.05
n4*0.05
```

get the sum from it

```
sum=(n1+n2+n3+n4)
```

and count the average based on total rows

is there a way to achieve that on mysql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `AVG` average function:

```
SELECT AVG(0.7*n1 + 0.1*n2 + 0.05*n3 + 0.05*n4) AS avg_value
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: whoa, so `AVG` could do thing like that?

Comment: @Blizz'ART Yeah, I was also surprised by this `:-)`